# Straightforward Question about conditional distributions

Tags: probability, integration

$X_1 \sim$ Unif[0,1]

$X_2 | X_1 \sim$ Unif [0, $X_1$]

Find $f_{X_2}(x_2).$

Obviously first find the joint, which you can determine from the conditional of $X_2$ and the pdf of $X_1$.  It is $\frac{1}{x_1}$.  I believe the support runs from $0 < x_1 < 1, 0 < x_2 <1$ (?)

To find $f_{X_2}(x_2)$, integrate out the $x_1.$  But if you do $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x_1} dx_1,$ you end up subtracting ln(0) from ln(1), which obviously doesn't work.  I'm wondering if my support for the joint is messed up, and if it shouldn't be $0<x_2<x_1<1$, leaving the integral to range from $x_2$ to 1.  But then the question is why, since $x_1$ can run over the entire range from 0 to 1?

Comment: Hint: Do you think the region around $(x_1,x_2)=(0.2,0.5)$ should lie in the support of the joint distribution? So, what is this support, if not the square $(0,1)^2$?

Comment: I'm not going to lie, I have had a hard time figuring out support changes when going from marginals to joints and back.  It's a real problem for me in joint transformations. But I've never seen your formulation before.  I will mull over.

Comment: What is the support of the conditional distribution of $X_2|X_1 = x_1$? Do not mess up with the support of the marginal distribution of $X_2$, which is $(0, 1)$. Once conditional on $X_1$, the support is changed.